# Read zip file from URL to ArrayBuffer with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have a front end javascript library into which I'm attempting to load a zip file. The libraries documentation suggests that if I wish to be loading a zip file from a URL (I do) then I need to have the data in an arraybuffer.

As I'm not a Javascript person I'm having some trouble discerning how I might be able to do this.

The code I believe that I ultimately need to use is the following, where I assume `buffer` is the name of my buffer:

```
shp(buffer).then(function(geojson){});
//or
shp.parseZip(buffer)->returns zip
```

So the question is, **if I have a file at `example.com/myfile.zip` how do I use vanilla javascript to get that into an ArrayBuffer?** I assume once that is done I'll have what I need to feed into that code snippet above.

Plenty of googleing keeps getting me results that don't seem relevant. The [File_API docs by Mozilla](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsArrayBuffer) don't provide an example that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetch`.

```
fetch('example.com/myfile.zip').then(res => res.arrayBuffer()).then(arrayBuffer => {
    // use ArrayBuffer
});
```

Comment: @anakaine Happy to help.